# links__system_main_menu in drupal not gettign called

Tags: routes

I created a theme and the theme name is abc. I am trying to override the default menu in drupal. I have the following filed in the theme folder (folder name is abc).

abc.info file and page.tpl and template.php file.

Inside the template.php I wrote the following

```
function abc_links__system_main_menu($variables) {
print_r($variables);die();
}
```

but this function never gets called. I already assigned the main menu to the header region through drupal admin. Drupal version is 7.

I have another function

```
function abc_menu_tree__main_menu($variables) {print_r($variables);die();
}
```

this function gets called without any issues.

Any help please

Comment: Have you already tried clearing the drupal cache?

Comment: yes I already tried clearing cache.

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/127577/cannot-get-theme-links-system-main-menuvariables-to-fire-now-matter-what them not calling this function